# difference between dot(.) and double colon (::) in accessing class method

Tags: ruby

A double colon(::) allows constants, instance methods, and class methods defined within a class or module, to be accessed from anywhere outside the class or module.

Looking at this example:

```
class Sample
   VAR_SAMPLE="what is the difference?"

  def self.show_var
    return VAR_SAMPLE
  end

  def method2
    return VAR_SAMPLE
  end
end

puts Sample::show_var # => what is the difference?
puts Sample.show_var # => what is the difference?
puts Sample::new::method2 # => what is the difference?
puts Sample.new.method2 # => what is the difference?
```

What is the difference in accessing class method using dot(.) and a double colon (::) operator then? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double colon `::` namespace operator can also be used as a message sending operator. In other words,

```ruby
foo.bar
```

can also be written as

```ruby
foo::bar
```

Except when not.

In particular, `.` is *always* a message send. `::` is *usually* a namespace lookup, except when it cannot possibly be. That means, for example, you cannot call a message that starts with an uppercase character, unless you also pass an argument list.

```ruby
foo = Class.new do
  def BAR; :method end
  BAR = :constant
end

foo.BAR    #=> :method
foo::BAR   #=> :constant
foo::BAR() #=> :method
```

The fact that `::` can also be used for message sends is a historical curiosity, and is banned in most style guides *except* for "class factories", i.e. methods that return classes. Imagine a web framework that is set up like this:

```ruby
module Controller
  def self.R(path)
    Class.new(AbstractController) do
      # a bunch of methods for dealing with routing to `path`
    end
  end
end

class IndexController < Controller::R '/index.html'
  def get
    render 'Welcome'
  end
end
```

In this case, in some style guides, it would be acceptable to write `Controller::R` because even though `R` is a method, it *returns* a class, so it kind-of acts like one.

But this is a special case for certain DSLs and is only allowed in certain style guides. Most style guides disallow `::` for message sends, because it is redundant with `.`, because it already has a another different meaning (namespace resolution), and because it doesn't behave like `.` in all cases.

> What is the difference in accessing class method using dot(.) and a double colon (::) operator then?

On the one hand, you can say, there is no difference because **when used as the message sending operator**, they both do the exact same thing.

On the other hand, there *is* a difference *in syntax*, namely that `foo::BAR` **isn't a message send**, it is a namespace lookup which is *completely different*. from `foo.BAR`, which is a message send.

Answer (score 0):

You can call ruby methods using following ways

using `Dot (.)`, `Double Colon (::)`, `send` method & `method` method

```
class Sample
   VAR_SAMPLE="what is the difference?"

  def self.show_var
    return VAR_SAMPLE
  end
  
  def method2
    return VAR_SAMPLE
  end
end
puts Sample::show_var
puts Sample.show_var
puts Sample.send(:show_var)
puts Sample.method(:show_var).call
puts Sample::new::method2
puts Sample.new.method2
puts Sample.send(:new).send(:method2)
puts Sample.method(:new).call.method(:method2).call
# All the above will return `what is the difference?` only
```

Now consider method which is a private

```
class Sample
   VAR_SAMPLE="what is the difference?"

  private
  def self.show_var
    return VAR_SAMPLE
  end
end
puts Sample::show_var # Will throw error private method `show_var' called for
puts Sample.show_var # Will throw error private  method `show_var' called for
puts Sample.send(:show_var) # what is the difference?
puts Sample.method(:show_var).call # what is the difference?
```

Note:- Other than this you can call ruby methods using other `metaprogramming` methods as well.

Comment: Class methods don't respect `private`, you will be able to call `Sample.show_var` in your last example

Comment: omg, I didn't know private won't work in class methods T_T

Comment: @slam but adding it to the eigenclass does e.g. `class Sample; VAR_SAMPLE="what is the difference?"; class << self; private; def show_var; VAR_SAMPLE; end;end;end` will cause `Sample.show_var` to raise "private method `show_var' called for Sample:Class"

Comment: I guess, there's some reasons behind https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method